# python memory error when trying make the dot product between 2 arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory, softmax

I am trying to use the derivative of softmax https://medium.com/@aerinykim/how-to-implement-the-softmax-derivative-independently-from-any-loss-function-ae6d44363a9d

this is the function that I use:

```
def softmax_grad(softmax):
    s = softmax.reshape(-1,1)
    return np.diagflat(s) - np.dot(s, s.T)
```

and when I call it I get this error

```
<ipython-input-72-4aed1c61658a> in softmax_prime(x)
      6 
      7     s = x.reshape(-1,1)
----> 8     return np.diagflat(s) - np.dot(s, s.T)

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\twodim_base.py in diagflat(v, k)
    306     s = len(v)
    307     n = s + abs(k)
--> 308     res = zeros((n, n), v.dtype)
    309     if (k >= 0):
    310         i = arange(0, n-k)

MemoryError:
```

is it because of the size? the array that i pass as parameter is of size (100, 60000) and the dot product is between shapes (600000, 1)
(1, 600000)

Answer (score 0):

This would produce an array of size (600000, 600000) which I'm assuming doesn't fit in your working memory.